# how to allow and deny access to devices to my wifi hostpot created on windows 7 (by mac address) in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, wifi, hotspot

I have a wifi hostspot created on my windows 7. I want to share my internet connection.
But i want to only allow the access to my wifi hotspot to some computers and deny the access to all others.
All the users knows the password, then What i need is some kind of access control based on mac address or some access control in this way.
Supose i have the shot spot and everybody knows the password. But i only want to give access to one device based on his mac address. 
That is the question.
I need to do in vb.net
Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: I have no code yet. I'm waiting for some idea about how to do this.

Comment: finally, the way is to use a radius authentication system. freeradius is the solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using router's page by MAC address filtering , you can program a code using vb.net to use a web browser and do this stuff.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment. Based control on mc address is not the right way. Any one with the user and pass need to have the access and i dont know the mc addresses...